# Where did 'konrad' go?

Tags: support

I was following this question for a while and all of a sudden `konrad` has appeared in the [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36148/29140):

[image: Snippet referencing <code>konrad</code>]

What was his involvement?

Can't see any reference to `konrad` being there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, Konrad posted an answer which was deleted by a moderator. The reason? Konrad didn't read the FAQ and tried to post a new question as an answer.

Comment: Somehow the site does not re-update to show the previous last edited user, making it quite confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely Konrad posted an answer that has since been deleted. Deleted posts are hidden from people with less than 10K reputation, but he still did update that question/its answers. (I don't have enough reputation to see, but it's consistent with an answer deletion.)

And, to be pedantic, we don't have "threads" here.